# Running script from console sotres cookies

Tags: php, cookies

I am running a php script from the console. I cannot see any cookies getting stored in local. Does anyone know if this is possible? If yes, what should I check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies is a browser feature. You cannot use it in console mode. (You can try to implement it yourself, please don't).

Answer (score 0):

COOKIES are not used when running PHP in CLI mode. See this question for some additional details: [Is it possible to read cookie/session value while executing PHP5 script through command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578595/is-it-possible-to-read-cookie-session-value-while-executing-php5-script-through)