# PHP script from command prompt - is it possible to set \ read cookies?

Tags: php, cookies, terminal, setcookie

I have a simple php page, and I'm trying to run this php script is from the terminal console (ssh):

```
php /home/account/domains/domain.com/public_html/script.php
```

Now, I can run the script, the thing is, if I'm running the php script from the console, setting \ reading a cookie doesn't work, If I'm running the same page from the browser, everything work just fine (Read and write cookies..)

So my question is, can I run this script from the terminal (just like above), and make the cookies save somehow?

**My php scrpit is simple:**

```
setcookie("cookie", "cookie", time()+30);
if (!isset($_COOKIE["cookie"])){
echo "New Cookie is set!";
}else{
echo "The Cookie already set!";
}
```

**Thank you very much for your help!**

Comment: Cookies are saved on the client. When running PHP from the command line, there is no client. All the `setcookie()` does is issue a header in the response to the client. The header contains the cookie name and value. No headers are issued/printed from the command line.

Comment: Hi Jonathen and thanks for your reply!, so, is there any "work around" to save\read cookies, after running php script from the terminal?

Comment: Where would you like to read them *from* and write them *to*? There's no client.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do by running the script in CLI?

Comment: right, understood, I just thought, if there is external service or similar, that will open a client, and will run it from there, It sound like a basic problem... Thanks!

Comment: I have a script that run every 2 seconds (shell script), then Im checking if I sent a value in the last 30 seconds, If i did, nothing will happen , otherwise, I'm sending this value.

Comment: Duplicate, and better answers here: [Is it possible to read cookie/session value while executing PHP5 script through command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578595/is-it-possible-to-read-cookie-session-value-while-executing-php5-script-through)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies only exist in a browser. There's no browser involved when you run a script from the command line, so there's nowhere for those cookies to be stored.

If you need to store data across calls to a command-line script, you will need to read and write it to a file. One simple way of doing this might be:

```
// At the start of the script...
$PERSIST = unserialize(file_get_contents("myscript.cache")) ?: array();

// Read data from there...
print $PERSIST["blah"];
// Write some
$PERSIST["foo"] = "stuff";

// At the end of the script, save it back
file_put_contents("myscript.cache", serialize($PERSIST));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the thing is, that it have to be existed for 30 seconds and then to kill itself, just like a cookie, i can write another shell script that delete this file, but It sounds like an ugly solution, also, I really don't want to create and delete files every 2 seconds, that will kill my HD :) , don't you think? thanks anyway!

Comment: If you need to keep track of when the script was last run, store the time in a file. Don't worry about the hard disk; it'll be fine.

Comment: Ok, I thought there is a better way, probably not, Thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to run some exec() functions, you can save cookies and things - see

[How to get past the login page with Wget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324421/how-to-get-past-the-login-page-with-wget)

Comment: That's a solution to a different problem than this. (Also, it's not a very good solution; the `curl` functions can store cookies just as well.)