# Passing variables to bash and php

Tags: php, bash, batch-file

Regarding [Is it possible to read cookie/session value while executing PHP5 script through command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578595/is-it-possible-to-read-cookie-session-value-while-executing-php5-script-through)
I tried to make a bash file that executes php and sets $_COOKIE before that.

I tried first in Windows environment creating simple batch file:

```
php -r "$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']='a095y187'; session_start(); $id_client=%1; $id_supplier=%2; $_COOKIE['id_chosen_client_auto']=$id_client; $_COOKIE['id_chosen_client']=$id_client; require 'manual_automap.php';"
```

Which works as i expected $_COOKIE is set and $id_client, and $id supplier were set with the first and second argument after the bat file:

```
manual_automap.bat 1 1
```

Now i try to migrate this on Linux environment and tried to change %1 and %2 to $1 and $2, but it seems this doesn't work like that. The variables are not set:

```
php -r "$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']='a095y187'; session_start(); $id_client=$1; $id_supplier=$2; $_COOKIE['id_chosen_client_auto']=$id_client; $_COOKIE['id_chosen_client']=$id_client; require 'manual_automap.php';"
```

What am i missing here?

I expect when run `manual_automap.sh 1 2` $id_client should be 1 and $id_supplier should be 2

Thanks.

PS: The php script i run is very old and **can't be changed**.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by replacing %1 to $1?

Comment: To pass the variables sent to sh file to php. According this link http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dosbatch.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape all $ signs (except $1 and $2).

```
php -r "\$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']='a095y187'; session_start(); \$id_client=$1; \$id_supplier=$2; \$_COOKIE['id_chosen_client_auto']=\$id_client; \$_COOKIE['id_chosen_client']=\$id_client; require 'manual_automap.php';"
```