# How can i execute phpunit tests on more than 1 website

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, phpunit, selenium-chromedriver

I have created a set of testcases created using phpunit and selenium that I execute on a website.  But now, there is a 2nd website for which I must execute the same tests.  The only difference is the url to access the website.

I have tried using a SESSION variable that is set to different value each time phpunit runs.  In the each test case I would reference this SESSION var but it is not working for me.  How do I deal with this?  I don't want to have 2 versions of identical testcases.

What I tried:

```
session_start();
    $environments = array('www.test1.com', 'www.test2.com');
    $arrlength = count($environments);

    for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
        $_SESSION['TEST_ENVIRONMENT'] = $environments[$x]; // Set session variable = environment
        phpunit -c phpunit.xml // xml file containing the testcases
        unset($_SESSION['TEST_ENVIRONMENT']); //Unset only TEST_ENVIRONMENT index in session variable
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of session variables I suggest you make use of [environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable). Environment variables allow you to tailor the environment a program or script runs in.

They also have less side-effects then sessions which [might not even work on the command-lone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29032312/367456). Also environment variables are more directly accessible within your test-suite. And they fulfill your need to pass a value to your test-suite.

So let's see an example:

```
$environments = array('www.test1.com', 'www.test2.com');
foreach ($environments as $environment) {
    putenv(sprintf("TEST_ENVIRONMENT=%s", $environment));
    passthru('phpunit -c phpunit.xml');
}
```

The [`putenv` php function](http://php.net/putenv) is used here to set the `TEST_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable. Then when phpunit is executed, the sub-shell phpunit is executed in has inherited the PHP-scripts environment.

In your tests, when you need to access that `TEST_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable, you can do it then with

```
getenv("TEST_ENVIRONMENT");
```

or

```
$_ENV["TEST_ENVIRONMENT"];
```

As you can see there is no need to start a session etc. and access is pretty straight forward.