# PHP sessions not showing up properly in terminal

Tags: php, linux, session, terminal, cron

I am currently building a small script for cron jobs, i am testing everything in the terminal (Linux) and i cant figure out why sessions are not working properly.

```
session_start()
$_SESSION['cron'] = 'test';
echo $_SESSION['cron'];
```

Comment: have you started the session? (`session_start()`)

Comment: did you start the session and does that array contain value in all other pages using sessions?

Comment: I just don't understand using sessions with cron though. Does that actually work?

Comment: i have session_start before everything, i need sessions to set old timestamp for each job

Comment: Session would not work from terminal , it works from browsers. However you can do like [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7578766/2815635)

Comment: check your logs then update your post to contain what those errors were, if any. Make sure that your system is setup to catch and log errors.

Comment: check once cron job is started or not, use this (crontab -e) command to your terminal

Comment: Sessions are a way of identifying the same visitor using a web browser to make multiple requests to a website. It's not clear how this would relate to the scenario of running under a terminal or a cron job, because there is no browser, and no visitor to track. I therefore think this is [an X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): you need to store some information between cron jobs, and sessions are the wrong tool for that job.

Comment: @IMSoP yes i agree this is the wrong way to store it but the only way i can think that would work is to write a temp file with the data i need

Comment: @Zoric Yes, a file, or an SQL database, or a NoSQL database, or an in-memory key-value store, or literally anything where you can read and write some data. Note that that's all a session does anyway: by default, each session is a file on disk, and you can set up session storage handlers for pretty much anything; the session part is entirely about keeping track of a visitor to a website, which is irrelevant to a cron job. Sessions gain you nothing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution

```
private function get($key){
    $content = @file_get_contents( __DIR__ . '/../../cron/data.json' );
    if ($content) {
        $content = json_decode($content, true);
        if ( is_array($content)) {
            return $content[$key];
        }else{
            return false;
        }           
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

private function request($key){
    $content = @file_get_contents( __DIR__ . '/../../cron/data.json' );
    if ($content) {

        $content = json_decode($content, true);
        if ( is_array($content)) {
            $content[$key] = time();
            file_put_contents( __DIR__ . '/../../cron/data.json' , json_encode($content) );
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }else{
        file_put_contents( __DIR__ . '/../../cron/data.json' , json_encode(['demo' => time()]) );
    }
}
```

Comment: please remember this is demo code, fix it up yourself

Comment: And how does this relate to your script in the question? I don't see any classes in there

Answer (score -3):

If I remember PHP correctly, you need to initialize sessions first :

```
session_start();
```

See the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php).

Comment: Food for thought: always give it a few minutes before posting an answer and looking at comments left under the post.

Comment: @Funk Forty Niner : you guys were commenting while I was writing my answer. :)